# Foundation interchange vs PageSpeed Insight

Tags: javascript, html, seo, pagespeed, zurb-foundation-6

I started to use Foundation Zurb mainly because of their interchange plugin that can swap image based on media-query. I got big banner on top of page that change its size based on mq.

We can use it this way

```
<img src="assets/img/interchange/small.jpg" data-interchange="[assets/img/interchange/small.jpg, small], [assets/img/interchange/medium.jpg, medium], [assets/img/interchange/large.jpg, large]">
```

Cool feature but the problem is that Page Speed Insight inform me ( Prioritize visible content section ) that it renders only 50% of visible top content when i use the plugin.

Page Speed suggest to load javascript async. So I have something like this in header:

```
<script async src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

I also started to use interchange from js like this:

```
var $photoFrame = $('#baner');
var interchange = new Foundation.Interchange($photoFrame, {
  rules: [
    "[assets/img/interchange/small.jpg, small]",
    "[assets/img/interchange/medium.jpg, medium]",
    "[assets/img/interchange/large, large]"
  ]
});
```

but it does not matter how i use it. PageSpeed just doesnt apprecieate that page needs to load additional jpg even async. 
If my javascript load async so it should not affect the time of rendering page. If in src attribute there is image it should render it and after js is loaded it should be swapped. I tried also without src, problem still persist.

Maybe I missunderstand what PageSpeed wanted to tell me but if i wont make it work I will have to abandon interchange and build baner with background-image and the way i use it now, the resolution of image determine the resolution of baner and by background approach it wont be that simple.